# How can I check if there is any Sunday falls between two dates selected?

Tags: c#

Currently i have 2 month calendars; one for starting date and the other for the ending date. A user can select any dates except sunday.There is also a button that checks the date if it is valid. If a user selected a range of dates containing sunday the system should not allow it and display a message that it is invalid. How do we do this using C#?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your work first. Have you ever check these dates difference is bigger or equal than `7` days or use `DayOfWeek` enumeration of your `DateTime`'s?

Comment: How is the date range represented? By two instances of `DateTime`?

Comment: @Soner Gonul -  I have put a code that will accept the selected range and i require a filter to remove date ranges that does have sundays

Comment: @Codor - I have used the instance MonthCalendar n = new MonthCalendar()  Textbox1.Text = n.SelectionStart.ToString(); Textbox2.Text = n.SelectionEnd.ToString();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just check the first 7 days of the selection.

Start on the first date selected and check this date, and the next 6, and do this:

- If you end up past the end date the user selected, you're done, all is good
- If you end up on a sunday, everything is not good

Something like this:

```
for (int index = 0; index < 7; index++)
{
    DateTime dt = startDate.AddDays(index);
    if (dt > endDate)
        return true;
    if (dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        return false;
}
```

Note that there is no point in checking *all* dates between the start and end date the user selected, since weeks is a 100% recurring pattern, it is enough to see if the selection starts with a week that contains a sunday.

Note that as mentioned in the comments, the for-loop is actually kinda unnecessary. Either we're going to hit the end-date, or we're going to find a sunday within 7 dates, so we can rewrite the above code to this:

```
DateTime dt = startDate;
while (dt <= endDate)
{
    if (dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        return false;
    dt = dt.AddDays(1);
}
```

*Personally* I find the first solution easier to understand and reason about.

Comment: I've upvoted since the solution is correct, however, I'd add that there's also no point on making a `for()` loop for 7 days, since it'll either get to `endDate` or find a Sunday anytime before the 7 comes... it'd be wiser to do `while(true) { /*rest of code*/ index++; }` and it would skip the comparison in the loop aswell (of course, just being picky :-) )

Comment: No, it's impossible that the loop will ever go further than 7 loops since there's **always** a Sunday in those first 7... best that can happen is that `endDate` comes before, and that'll make it less than 7. Worst case scenario is that `Sunday` comes at index 6. Comparing with 7 in the loop is redundant (well, not redundant, but unnecesary). Again, I was just being picky :-)

Comment: I retracted my comment when I saw what you meant, I've edited the answer to effect.

Comment: I agree with you, was being picky for the sake of optimization, but yes, first one is much more readable. As stated in other answer's comments, you could also do a `if((endDate-startDate).TotalDays>=7) return false` for further optimization if values are to be usually greater than one week.

Comment: I don't know why but I keep coming back to this question! Taking your edit, how about `while(dt <= endDate) { /* check for sunday and increment */ } return true;` so that it doesn't look like an infinite loop? :-)

Comment: Having `while (true)` is strange, especially when you have inside condition to break loop `if (dt > endDate) return true;` Just move this condition to `while` and avoid infinite loop. See my answer for sample.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen  just a side question,, does the use of a return statement inside the for/while will cause it to break the loop? Thanks

Comment: @IvanMatala it'll both break the loop and return from the calling function without executing any code after the loop

Answer (score 3):

assuming you do a check for end date is not before the start date

```
while(start <= stop)
{
    if(start.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        // carry on if you don't want any basic functions done per check
    }
    else
    {
         //what ever you do if is sunday
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have concept of [Range](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/Range.html) then consider to create appropriate data type for it. I would recommend to implement dates range as a [Value Object](http://culttt.com/2014/04/30/difference-entities-value-objects/):

```
public class DateRange
{
   public DateTime Start { get; private set; }
   public DateTime End { get; private set; }

   public DateRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
   {
       if (endDate < startDate)
          throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("endDate");

       Start = startDate;
       End = endDate;
   }
}
```

Now when you have this data type its easy to add appropriate behavior for range of dates. You can add checking if some date falls in this range, or (in your case) if some day of week falls in range:

```
public bool Contains(DayOfWeek day)
{
    var date = Start;

    while(date <= End)
    {
        if (date.DayOfWeek == day)
           return true;

        date = date.AddDays(1);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now your code will look like:

```
var range = new DateRange(startDate, endDate);
if (range.Contains(DayOfWeek.Sunday))
     // show error message
```

Note - there is no need for optimizations like checking only first 7 days, thus you either find your day of week, or you will reach end date.

Comment: As a further optimization, a `if((End-Start).TotalDays>=7) return true` at the start of `Contains` should be quicker than the loop for those cases. Whether that's worth checking depends on actual usage though :-)

Comment: @Jcl usually I try to avoid premature optimizations, but agree, this is a good check. I would also add another optimization `if (End.DayOfWeek == day || Start.DayOfWeek == day) return true;` to avoid even calculation of TimeSpan.

Comment: Actually, taking OP's usage of this algorithm, any optimizations for such a simple function are pointless, but just for the sake of trying to make it as good as possible in any usage scenarios :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, please don't use it in production since it depends on the implementation of the DayOfWeek enumeration:

```
public static bool DateRangeContainsASunday(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        int days = (end - start).Days;
        return days => 7 || (int)end.DayOfWeek - days <= 0;
    }
```